# Explorting an RGL object for use in WebGL

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I've got a 3D PCA plot using the pcaplot method from AffyCoreTools in R
http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=affycoretools/man/plotPCA.Rd&d=R_BC

I'd like to capture this object and my overall aim is to use that dynamic, interactive plot in a web page (potentially rendering with webGL), but for the moment I'm stuck in actually capturing the Object that pcaplot() is creating.

I've tried `foo <- pcaplot()` which y`NULL` object.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just have to put `writeWebGL()` with a file path to where you want the output placed prior to calling `pcaplot()`. You didn't include any data or code which would allow me to try it out first, but assuming the plotting function is calling `rgl` in a friendly way, then [writeWebGL](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/writeWebGL) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks - The code I called before plotting the 3D object, works like a dream. - `writeWebGL(dir = "webGL", filename = file.path("webGL/index.html"), 
template = system.file(file.path("WebGL", "template.html"), package = "rgl"),
snapshot = TRUE, font = "Arial")`

Answer (score 0):

all I had to do was put

library(rgl)

pca3d(set.final.pca, group=set.final$Groups,show.labels = TRUE,show.centroids = TRUE,show.ellipses=FALSE, show.group.labels=FALSE)
rglwidget()